# how to split one file into many file, If repeated term come in column 1?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have big file name as file.txt which contains data like this:

```
1  1.1  
2  1.2  
3  1.3  
4  1.4  
5  1.5  
1  2.1  
2  2.2  
3  2.3  
4  2.4   
1  2.5  
2  2.8  
3  3.1
```

So I want output like this, If  1 repeat in First column then it should split the file like this :---

a.txt :

```
1  1.1  
2  1.2  
3  1.3  
4  1.4  
5  1.5
```

b.txt :

```
1  2.1  
2  2.2  
3  2.3  
4  2.4
```

c.txt:

```
1  2.5  
2  2.8  
3  3.1
```

Comment: what is the rule it based on?

Comment: welcome to SO, Please post what is your effort, what you have tried so far, what error you are facing in doing that.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU csplit & parallel):

```
csplit -sz file '/^1 /' '{*}'
parallel mv ::: xx?? :::+ {a..z}.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

***Solution for OP's question:*** Could you please try following(where OP mentioned in his/her post that output files should be `a.txt` or `b.txt` etc). Since OP did not mention once all alphabets output files got created what should happen so I have written program where once 27th occurrence of 1 happens then it will keep using files from `a` again and keep appending to already existing files.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  split("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z",array,",")
}
$1==1{
  close(file)
  file=array[++count]".txt"
  count=count==26?0:count
}
{
  print >> file
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT(solution from OP's comment that OP wants output files in `1.txt`,`2.txt` etc forms):*** In case you want to create output files like `1.txt`, `2.txt` etc then try following. Whenever a `1` comes in 1st field it will start writing output into a new output file.

```
awk '$1==1{close(file);file=++count".txt"}  {print > file}'  Input_file
```

Adding explanation for above command:

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program here.
$1==1{                       ##Checking condition if $1(first field) of current line is equal to 1 then do following.
  close(file)                ##Using close awk function to close output file whose name is stored in variable named file.
  file=++count".txt"         ##Creating a variable named file whose value is increment variable count value with .txt string.
}                            ##Closing BLOCK for condition here.
{
  print > file               ##Printing all lines to output file whose names is stored in variable file here.
}
'   Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Above command will create 3 output files(as per your samples) as follows:

```
cat 1.txt
1  1.1  
2  1.2  
3  1.3  
4  1.4  
5  1.5  
cat 2.txt
1  2.1  
2  2.2  
3  2.3  
4  2.4   
cat 3.txt
1  2.5  
2  2.8  
3  3.1
```

***PS:*** I have taken care of "too many files opened" error by using `close(file)` command in program(s).

Comment: @daizy123, what should happen in case `1`'s count is coming more than 26(counts of alphabets)? is it needed to be reset to 1, please let us know.

Comment: using this command it is giving me this error:awk: r.txt makes too many open files
 input record number 115601, file time_org.txt
 source line number 1

Comment: how to creat number file let say 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt.......upto N.txt, because data is large in my input file. That was only sample file

Comment: @daizy123, in case you need files like `1.txt` etc then try my EDIT command?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care too much about the filenames, then they can just be numbers

```
 awk '(NR==1)||($1<t) { close(f); f=sprintf("%0.5d",i++)}{print > f; t=$1}'
```

Comment: and if you do need letters then `f=sprintf("%c.txt", 97+(i++))`.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you could use python, try this:

```py
counter = 1
output = None
with open('file.txt', 'r') as input:
    while True:
        line = input.readline()
        if line is None or len(line) == 0:
            break
        if line[0] == '1':
            if output is not None:
                output.close()
                output = None
        if output is None:
            output = open(str(counter) + '.txt', 'w')
            counter = counter + 1
        output.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

here a alternative with bash

```
#!/bin/bash
count=96                                                 # char before 'a'
while read line; do                                      # loop over all lines
   tag=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f1)                    # get line tagger
   if [ "$tag" == "1" ]; then                            # group change on 1
       let "count = count + 1"                           # count file
       filename="$(printf "\\$(printf %o $count)").txt"  # create filename
       >$filename                                        # initial file
   fi
   echo "$line" >> $filename                             # append to file
done < file.txt                                          # input from file.txt
```